# Loop through matrix, find row values that meet constraint, create new column

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, constraints

I am sure something similar has been answered before, but I am new to MATLAB and currently stuck with a very simple problem. I have a matrix `M` and I would like to do the following: Loop through all the values of a column `C` and if any of these values are not equal to some value, `x` copy the corresponding values over into another column in the matrix (call it `Z`), while leaving those values that did not satisfy the condition alone.

I have tried the following, but it's not doing anything:

```
rows = size(M,1);

for i = 1:rows
   if M(:,x) ~= 0
      then M(:,Z) = M(:,x) 
   end 
end
```

Comment: what are `x` and `Z` in your code? You are not using the loop variable `i` in your code - what's the point in iterating if you are not using `i`???

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! x and z are just placeholders for column numbers. Say if x was 10 and z was 20, I'd want the values in column 10 that are non-zero to show up in column 20.

Comment: Sorry - I hit enter prematurely there. 
I was wondering how to initialise i, yes. This is just what I found in teh code samples online. In order to check the values of column 10 against my constraint I want to loop through column 10 row by row. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Algebreaker: Do you want the corresponding non-zero positions in column `x` to **replace** those values in column `Z`?  As an example, supposing that in column `x`, we encounter non-zero values in rows 1, 2, 4, 7, 8.  Do you want column `Z` to have rows 1, 2, 4, 7, 8 to be **replaced** with those corresponding values from column `x`?

Comment: @Algebreaker: Looking at your explanation in your post and comparing your code, they conflict with each other.  Let's go back to your post then.  1.  What happens when the column `C` has an element that **is equal to `x`**?  2.  *"copy the value into a new column at the end of the matrix"*:  What happens **when there is more than one value that's != `x`** - 2b) Where do these values go?  3. In general, **where** do the values get copied over in the column?  There is a lot of info that is missing and depending on how you answer, the code will be vastly different between each interpretation.

Comment: @rayryeng: Thanks for your post. And sorry for being so unclear - I wanted to keep it short and sweet so simplified things a bit which as it turns out wasn't a good idea...
To answer your questions:

Comment: - Yes, I want them replaced although that's not strictly what I will be doing as column z is a new column I added to the matrix. So it only has 0s in it anyway...
- when column c has a value that is equal to x nothing should happen, i.e. the loop should just move to the next row.
- I don't quite understand your question about more than one value !=x. The values would all go to the corresponding rows in column z...?
So the values are supposed to go into the aequivalent position in column z.

Comment: Here's an example:
Let a = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 10]. And let the 1st column be x and the 3rd z. So I would like a loop that checks if all the values in column x are different form 1 and copies the value to z. In our case the second and third row values are different from 1 (they are 4 and 7). So I now want the new matrix to be a = [1 2 3; 4 5 4; 7 8 7]. Hope that's clearer?

Comment: OK, that's actually not bad at all.  You neglected to mention that you have a third variable: call it `d`, that you want to compare to.  I'll write an answer for you.  We can escape `for` loops all together.

Comment: @Algebreaker: I have placed an answer. Let me know if this is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your comments, this is the gist of what you want to accomplish:

1. Given a matrix `A`, choose two columns in this matrix: `x` and `Z`.
2. Given a value `d`, we wish to find all values within `x` that are **different** than some value, `d`.
3. Take these locations in `x` and copy them over to the corresponding locations in `Z`.

Let's do this step by step.  Given your example in your comments:

```
% // Step #1
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 10];
x = 1; % //Column x
Z = 3; % //Column Z
d = 1; % //Value to compare to

% //Step #2
loc = A(:,x) ~= d;

%//Step #3
A(loc, Z) = A(loc, x);
```

Since you're new to MATLAB, let's go through this slowly.  The first step is pretty basic MATLAB syntax.  It's choosing your parameters as well as some basic set up.  The second step will give us a **logical** array that tells us which rows in column `x` are **not equal to `d`**.  The last step will find these corresponding rows in column `Z` and copy these values over from column `x` over to `Z`.

The great thing about MATLAB is that it does these kinds of *vectorized* operations natively.  The best thing for optimization is to try to **avoid for loops** as much as you can.  Only use `for` loops if you have to repeat heavy computations, or situations where you absolutely cannot avoid `for` loops.

As a bonus, let's see how MATLAB displays each step that we've talked above (except the first one as it's redundant).

```
% //Step #2
loc = A(:,x) ~= d

>> loc

loc =

     0
     1
     1

%// Step #3
A(loc, Z) = A(loc, x)

>> A =

     1     2     3
     4     5     4
     7     8     7
```

Note that `loc` is a logical array such that `0` is false, and `1` is true.  As such, rows 2 and 3 satisfy the condition that these values are not equal to `d`.

Also, FWIW, welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Brilliant, you just made my day! This works perfectly and is so much easier than my inital approach (plus I actually understand what is going on!)! I guess reading programming text books makes you want to use loops everywhere...
Thanks again for your help - very much appreciated!

Comment: @Algebreaker: You're very welcome, and I'm glad you know what's going on!  I used to give several MATLAB tutorials at my university when I was doing my PhD and was an instructor there... so it's nice to see that those skills are still being put to use here.  Welcome to StackOverflow!